# Why is admob not working in android build but it does in unity editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I used Admob to put ads on my game, when i test it on unity the ad works perfectly fine but when I build the game and test it live no ad is showing.

The script I'm using is that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class BannerGA : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    BannerView _bannerView;

    void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize((InitializationStatus initStatus) =>
        {
            CreateBannerView();
            LoadAd();
        });
    }

    public void CreateBannerView()
    {
        Debug.Log("Creating banner view");

        if (_bannerView != null)
        {
            DestroyAd();
        }

        _bannerView = new BannerView(_adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        ListenToAdEvents();
    }

    public void LoadAd()
    {
        if (_bannerView == null)
        {
            CreateBannerView();
        }
        var adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.Keywords.Add("unity-admob-sample");

        Debug.Log("Loading banner ad.");
        _bannerView.LoadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void ListenToAdEvents()
    {
        _bannerView.OnBannerAdLoaded += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Banner view loaded an ad with response : "
                + _bannerView.GetResponseInfo());
        };
        _bannerView.OnBannerAdLoadFailed += (LoadAdError error) =>
        {
            Debug.LogError("Banner view failed to load an ad with error : "
                + error);
        };
        _bannerView.OnAdPaid += (AdValue adValue) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(String.Format("Banner view paid {0} {1}.",
                adValue.Value,
                adValue.CurrencyCode));
        };
        _bannerView.OnAdImpressionRecorded += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Banner view recorded an impression.");
        };
        _bannerView.OnAdClicked += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Banner view was clicked.");
        };
        _bannerView.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Banner view full screen content opened.");
        };
        _bannerView.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Banner view full screen content closed.");
        };
    }

    public void DestroyAd()
    {
        if (_bannerView != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Destroying banner ad.");
            _bannerView.Destroy();
            _bannerView = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to show ads on my game using Admob for Unity, the ads are showing on the unity editor but not on the live test, i tried in different android devices.